# Coordinate Point Drops on timeseries in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, time-series, timemanager

I have timestamp data for every minute of a day (1140)for multiple objects by id, with a corresponding lat long. I want to get the time in which an id disappears off the map or off the csv. What would be the best tool, and is QGIS the best route?

Comment: Explain what you mean by off the map? What happens if you object returns multiple times may be due to signal loss or if it wanders out of some specified boundary? It would help to explain what this time stamped data actually is. Animal tracking  or trains, quite different solutions!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're essentially looking for the largest timestamp value (the latest record) for each ID. You can accomplish this with a virtual layer and SQL query in QGIS:

Create a new virtual layer by going to *Layer* > *Add Layer* > *Add/Edit Virtual Layer*.

[image]

Hit the *Import* button to add a layer that is already in your map, and then modify that example SQL query so it is selecting from the *Local Name* of the layer you just imported.